# Words hiererchical semantic distance

Tags: nlp, dataset, semantics, hierarchical-data

I need a labeled data (human judgment) for the structural/hierarchical semantic distance between many couples (at least hundreds) of word.

For example, d(computer, television) < d(radio, television) < d(dish washer, television).

If we organize all words in a dendogram or a tree, where each node is a category ("electric device", "with screen", etc...), and words are in leaves, the number will represent number of steps (nodes) we have to go from one word to another.

Does such dataset exist?
per couples ratings is enough, no need to have a full embeding/tree/specify the nodes
(An example dataset will be:

Computer Television 1

Radio Television 2

DishWasher Television 3

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm now aware of such human judgements datasets, but I guess you could look at [semantic networks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_network) like **WordNet** which is a lexical database of English in a form of a graph. Given two words, you could compute distance between nodes representing them in WordNet.

> Both nouns and verbs are organized into hierarchies, defined by
>   hypernym or IS A relationships. For instance, one sense of the word
>   dog is found following hypernym hierarchy; the words at the same level
>   represent synset members. Each set of synonyms has a unique index.
>
> ```
> dog, domestic dog, Canis familiaris
>  canine, canid
>   carnivore
>    placental, placental mammal, eutherian, eutherian mammal
>     mammal
>      vertebrate, craniate
>       chordate
>        animal, animate being, beast, brute, creature, fauna
>         ...
> ```

If you are looking for a dataset, you could also ask [here](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: thanks for the dataset ref, didn't know it. I'll ask there. I'm familiar with WordNet but it is not good enough since it was hand-defined and has some definitions that are not really precise. I want to use WordNet with word2vec distance, but for that I want to have the human judgment data as labels.